# Read (not select) active options from a Multi-Select dropdown using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

There are many questions and answers for selecting multiple options in a Multi-select dropdown, but few, if any, that deal with only reading currently selected options.

How can the "active" options be read from the following Multi-select dropdown? Note that Widget A and Widget C are active and Widget B is not.

It seems like you would use [Select.all_selected_options](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.all_selected_options). Xpath to the multi-select-container is `//*[@id="addActivityTable"]/tbody/tr[17]/td[2]/div/ul`.

**HTML**

```html
<table id="addActivityTable" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><b> Vendor Approved Widgets</b></td>
      <td colspan="3">
      <select name="WidgetStatus_DD" id="WidgetStatus_DD" class="text2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 200px; display: none;">
          <option value="multiselect-all"> Select all</option>&nbsp;
          <option value="123" selected="">&nbsp;WIDGET A</option>
          <option value="456">&nbsp;WIDGET B</option>
          <option value="789" selected="">&nbsp;WIDGET C
        <div class="btn-group open">
          <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="&nbsp;WIDGET A
                                                
                                                    , &nbsp;WIDGET B
                                                
                                                " aria-expanded="true">2 selected <b class="caret"></b></button>
            <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" mylist="" data-input="#filtersearch" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true" style="max-height: 200px; overflow: hidden auto;">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 4px 9px;">
                        <img src="/css/e003.jpg">
                    </span>
                    <input id="filtersearch" class="form-control multiselect-search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="multiselect-all">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                          <input type="checkbox" value="multiselect-all">
                          " Select all"
                        </label>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="123"> &nbsp;WIDGET A
                        </label>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="456"> &nbsp;WIDGET B
                        </label>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="789"> &nbsp;WIDGET C
                        </label>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This was my attempt that fails:

```
def get_selected_values_from_dropdown(self, xpath):
    try:
        select = Select(WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))))
        return select.all_selected_option.get_attribute("value")
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        print(f"Dropdown element at {xpath} not found.")

xpath = '//*[@id="addActivityTable"]/tbody/tr[17]/td[2]/div/ul'
record = dict()
if key == "widgets":
    widgets = self.get_selected_values_from_dropdown(xpath)
    record[key] = ", ".join(widgets)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the active option elements you can use this:

```
active_options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='active']//label")
```

**UPD**
After you updated the HTML.
I can't be sure since I can't see the other dropdowns, but if this specific dropdown block unique locator is `id="addActivityTable"` the code above will be

```
active_options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[id='addActivityTable']//li[@class='active']//label")
```

or maybe

```
active_options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[id='addActivityTable']//td[@colspan='3']//li[@class='active']//label")
```

Also, possibly you can do it in some other way, like this:

```
active_options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[id='addActivityTable']//td[@colspan='3']//option[@selected]")
```

To give a certain answer I still need to see the other dropdowns on that page

Comment: Is this all you asking for or you wish to extract the widget letter from the element text too? It can be completed simple.

Comment: No, I don't need to extract the letter, just the active options complete text. I'll take a look at this and provide feedback shortly. Thank you.

Comment: This is getting closer, but not the solution. It selects all active options on the whole page, not just for the specific dropdown.

Comment: Right. But you didn't mention that there are several dropdowns there. Also, I can't see in the HTML block you shared any parent element for that whole block with some unique locators.

Comment: I've been using Xpath to locate objects, shown above, to locate the multiselect-container dropdown-menu ul element; //*[@id="addActivityTable"]/tbody/tr[17]/td[2]/div/ul. I am also working in Google Colab, and unused to debugging there or I'd add more detail.

Comment: Can you share a link to that page? I'll take a look tomorrow

Comment: The page is secured, but I've updated the HTML with a wider context up to the containing table. Thank you.